# Failed to load module fglrx (module does not exist 0) on Backtrack 5

Tags: fglrx, failover

I have uninstalled fglrx modules and ati modules in order to re-install them.after the rebooting the i cant come up with GUI....
On startx it displays

Failed to load module fglrx (module does not exist 0) 
No drivers available
ddxsiggiveup :closing log
giving up
xinit: No such file or directory (errno 2).unable to connect to Xserver
xinit : No such process(errno 3): Server Error

Comment: For distributions other than Ubuntu, try our friends at http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Indeed, I hope you find a good answer, but [BackTrack is not supported here](http://askubuntu.com/faq), so we'll probably close this question. There are many places where you can get community support for BackTrack, including [BackTrack forums](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/forums/forum.php) and (as Jorge Castro suggested) [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

*Try:*

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle
```

If that doesn't work:

```
sudo apt-get purge xorg-driver-fglrx fglrx*
sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle
```

If that doesn't work then there's definetley **something wrong with the driver** or possibly your hardware (not likeley).

```
sudo apt-get purge xorg-driver-fglrx fglrx*
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri fglrx-modaliases
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

...And (you will probrably need this in the future and it told system settings what driver I was using) **install mesa-utils**.

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```